# BlenderGIS: Basemap is not rendering along with the object

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

I create an animation of camera around my object which is referenced on the basemap. When I try to render the animation or just the image, I only see the Blender object. What do I need to do make the basemap also part of it?

In this screenshot you can see how my Rendered results don't match the camera view

[image]

Comment: You have imported the image as a reference, which is basically an empty object displaying the image in the viewport. Empties will not be rendered. You have to put the image on a regular plane object.